# PHP AJAX Change value based on combobox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I want is every time I have change the value from combobox (value from combobox is from database ) the input type will change too

here

```
<div class="col-md-12" >
    <label>Charge</label>
    <select id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
    <?php
        while ($reserve=mysqli_fetch_array($charge)) { ?>
           <option value=" <?php echo $reserve['name']?>">
               <?php echo $reserve['name']; ?>
           </option><?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<br>
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Price" name="Price" disabled>
</div>
```

on database the name has a corresonding price for example chair has 200 price
what I want is every time I changed the combobox the value at inputtype will change too

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: i tried to do this 
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" disabled value="<?=$reserve['price']?>"><?php } ?>

Comment: you need ajax for this?

Comment: What @JayBlanchard said. You just need to read the docs on both [JS ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) and [PHP while loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php). Then when you've tried something and have read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) come back and ask a question that shows us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you use ajax if you want to show option value . please check this code .

```js
 $('#name').change(function () {
            var option_value = $(this).val();
            $('#Price').val(option_value);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="name" name="name">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>


    <div class="col-md-12">
                <br>
                <label>Price</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Price" name="Price" disabled>
              </div>
</form>
```

so update  select code using your this code

```
<select id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
                  <?php
                  while ($reserve=mysqli_fetch_array($charge)) { ?>
                    <option value=" <?php echo $reserve['name']?>">
                      <?php echo $reserve['name']; ?>
                    </option><?php } ?>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Jquery code to accomplish this task.
Your Html :

```
<div class="col-md-12" >
  <label>Charge</label>
  <select id="name" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
    <?php while ($reserve=mysqli_fetch_array($charge)) { ?>
    <option value=" <?php echo $reserve['name']?>">
    <?php echo $reserve['name']; ?>
    </option><?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12"><br>
  <label>Price</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Price" name="Price" disabled>
</div>
```

Jquery Code :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#name").change(function () {
        var value = this.value;
        $('#Price').val(value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                    <select id="name" name="name" class="form-control" onchange="callAjax(this)">
                      <?php
                      while ($reserve=mysqli_fetch_array($charge)) { ?>
                        <option value=" <?php echo $reserve['name']?>">
                          <?php echo $reserve['name']; ?>
                        </option><?php } ?>
                    </select>

<script>
    function callAjax(val){
        var selectedVal = val.value;
        alert(selectedVal+"  "+val)
        $.ajax({
            url: "<some_Url>", // Use PHP url from where you can get Data from Database
            data: selectedVal,
            success: function(result){
                $("#Price").val(result);
        }});


    }
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.